# Universal links iOS error

Tags: ios, deep-linking

In my server(https) i have the apple-app-site-association file, with the next content

```
{
   applinks: {
   apps: [ ],
   details: [
   {
      appID: "{Prefix}.{bundleId}",
      paths: [
     "*"
             ]
   }
   ]
   }
}
```

but when i test con with the validation tool, https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ ,

i get this error

[image: Errror]

the documentation says that the apple-app-site-association file should to place in the root directory of the server

https://domain.com/apple-app-site-association

I did request to the server admin of my job the upload the file and
and he have not placed the file in the root, else

https://domain.com/**something**/apple-app-site-association

there any problem with that?

another question: My app is of development, therefore it isn't in el app store, but this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection says :

"real app on the App Store it is necessary for test universal links",that's true ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. The `apple-app-site-association` file *must* be in either the domain root or the `.well-known` directory. iOS will not check for it anywhere else. That is the current cause of your **Error cannot fetch app site association**.
2. Ray's tutorial is correct: the app need not be in the App Store for Universal Links to work. The error messages on Apple's validator are extremely confusing, because they don't necessarily have anything to do with whether Universal Links are functional. Even domains that definitely work with Universal Links (https://google.com, https://jet.com, for example) still throw errors on Apple's validator. Officially, it is comparing your website's `apple-app-site-association` file to your app's listing on the App Store, so if the version of your app that is publicly available does not yet have Universal Links entitlements, that often contributes to an error. However, Universal Links will still work fine with local builds.

You can try [a different validator](https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/) for your file. You might also consider a free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) to handle all of this configuration for you.

Comment: "the app need not be in the App Store for Universal Links to work" need or not need ? I have two app, (release and debug) debug i can configure it, release app not (I have to follow a bureaucratic process)

Comment: Need *not*. Local debug builds of your app will work fine with Universal Links even if the version of your app in the App Store does not yet support them.